# 5 month old dog keeps picking up older smaller dog by her neck

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression

We just adopted Blue, a 5 months old female husky/German Shepherd mix who's about 40 lbs (around 18 kg), and we have Nani, an almost 5 years old Basenji who weighs 14 lbs (around 6.5 kg). They seemed to get along quite fine until yesterday.

Yesterday, Blue picked up the Nani by the scruff of her neck and Nani yelped pretty loudly while she was being held and we had to physically correct her for her to let go of Nani. Once Blue released Nani, she ran towards the back door to the yard (as if she wanted to get out), sat down and was shaking. This happened again this morning.

I'm not sure if this is just Blue not knowing when her playing style goes too far or if this is something else, but this is quite scary for us as we're afraid that this could turn extremely dangerous and not end well for the younger dog.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell us where you got Blue from? A private breeder or shelter or anything?

Comment: she was adopted....some one found her on the side of the road and then we adopted her...origins are unknown...

Comment: Perhaps Blue thinks Nani is a puppy who she's adopted? Carrying an older dog by the scruff of it's neck is painful for them. So, Blue hurt Nani (without meaning to). A dominance issue, not a playtime issue. Blue wants to be "Nani's Mom".